# Variance of derangements

Tags: probability, permutations, random-variables

Suppose I choose a random permutation on n numbers. It is easy to prove that the mean of the number of fixed points (i.e. the numbers that get mapped to themselves) is 1. Is there an easy (constant) bound like this on the variance of this random variable ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

One uses the same trick (sorry, not trick, **method**) as for the mean. Let $X_i=1$ if $i$ is fixed, and $0$ otherwise. Then $Y=X_1+\cdots+X_n$ is the number of fixed points.

To find the variance of $Y$, we compute $E(Y^2)$ and subtract the square of the (known) mean.

To calculate $E(Y^2)$, expand $(X_1+\cdots+X_n)^2$ and use the linearity of expectation. For $i\ne j$, $E(X_iX_j)$ is not hard to calculate, since $X_iX_j=1$ if and only if $i$ and $j$ are both fixed.

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem.

Comment: You are welcome. Linearity of expectation is a powerful tool, it enables us to bypass finding the distribution explicitly. And even if we have the distribution, the standard expression for the mean leads to an often messy expression, for which there may be no obvious simplification.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, every moment of the number of fixed points is eventually constant: for any $m \ge 1$, $E(X^m)$ is equal to the $m$th [Bell number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number), provided the number of elements $n$ is at least $m$.

See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation_statistics#Moments_of_fixed_points